# Examples of products/libraries that use log4net

Tags: log4net

This isn't exactly a technical question, but I figured folks here might be a good resource.  I'm preparing a presentation about log4net and I'd like to cite some well known products/projects/libraries that have incorporated log4net.  Part of this is motivated to let the audience know how well established the tool is and the other is to demonstrate how the output from referenced assemblies can be incorporated into the logging output of your application.

I know nHibernate and StructureMap use it, but I'd like to really bury the slide in names/logos of applications that use log4net.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

[CruiseControl.Net](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Welcome+to+CruiseControl.NET) uses log4net...

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This would answer the question even if the link does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have an Acer laptop and at least some of the Acer supplied utilities (called something like Acer Empowering Technology tools) used it.

Don't have access to the laptop now, but I did google search for 'acer empowering log4net' just to check my memory wasn't faulty.

If you are just looking for logos, then the first link that came up in the search http://www.exe-dll.com/dll/log4net.dll.htm also shows some other possible users including LinkSys, Motorola

Answer (score 0):

One thing I find appealing about log4net is that it is related to log4j, the original one of the pair.  This means that since I understand how to configure log4j, I also know how to configure log4net.  The log4j package is used extensively in the java world.  Oracle's Weblogic is a good example, and you can likely find more out there.
I believe this is a very appealing attribute, as there is more to this world than MS applications.